# How to substring environment variable in gocd pipeline

Tags: python, docker, go-cd

```
pipelines:
  my-docker-build:
    group: *GROUP
    label_template: ${env:COMMIT_HASH[:8]}
    lock_behavior: unlockWhenFinished
    display_order: -1
    parameters:
      ECR: *ECR
    environment_variables:
      COMMIT_HASH: ""
```

I assign `COMMIT_HASH` as environment in gocd pipeline and which has around 30 characters. But I want to substring the first 8 characters as docker tag in gocd like `${env:COMMIT_HASH[:8]}`. Unfortunately, substring is not working and it tagged full 30 character as docker tag. Please let me know how to substring environment variable in gocd pipeline. Thanks.